# Horizontal UIScrollView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a simple scrollView inside a tableview cell. Just like on app store, but with simpler scrolling.

The scrollview is showing up but its not scrolling at all. I've tried whole first page on google and many stackoverflow questions, can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

```
 if (indexPath.row==0) {
    // Clearing out cell background
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // Imageviews for scrollview
    UIImageView *imageview1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,123)];
    UIImageView *imageview2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320,0,320,123)];

    imageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flash2.png"];
    imageview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_2458.JPG"];

    // setting up scrollview
    self.scrollViewHeader = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 123)];
    self.scrollViewHeader.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollViewHeader.delegate = self;
    [self.scrollViewHeader setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollViewHeader setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 123)];
    [self.scrollViewHeader addSubview:imageview1];
    [self.scrollViewHeader addSubview:imageview2];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.scrollViewHeader];
}
else{
// Normal table cells.
...
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Would paging in a tableview cell be more effective for what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a scroll view to scroll, its content size must be greater than its bounds.

You have:

```
self.scrollViewHeader = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 123)];
```

and then

```
[self.scrollViewHeader setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 123)];
```

In this case, they are both the same size, therefore it won't scroll. Do:

```
self.scrollViewHeader = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160, 123)];
[self.scrollViewHeader setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 123)];
```